# How can you find a pattern within X words? Attempting to re-create dtsearch w/n logic

Tags: regex

The real deal has a bit more words I'm searching for, but the basic idea is that I am looking for **date** *within 5 words of* **(birthday|birth date|birthdate)**

Trying to have this done in both directions (*2/1/2020 word1 birthday* as well as *birthday word1 2/1/2020*)

I'm not using any kind of Python RegEx variations. Essentially limited to a text editor due to limited resources.

Comment: Please give some sample strings with the match that you want and tell us which text editor you are using. Python is installed on most unix/linux OS and is avaliable foc for Windows etc..  If you are on windows and dont want to install anything try powershell ?

Comment: I am using EditPadPro 8.
Example strings:

"Soandso's birthday is on 2/15/90"
(match would be 2/15/90.  If just matching date isn't possible, matching the string "birthday is on 2/15/90" would also work)

"2/15/90 - registered birthday of employee Bob"
(Match would be 2/15/90. If can't just match date, "2/15/90 - registered birthday" could also work)

Essentially, if a date is within X words of Y, where X is a number and Y is a chosen word, then the date would match. If not possible, then everything between and including X and Y would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pattern look for a group of numbers which looks like a date a maxiumum of 5 spaces between it and one of the key words.
NB The 'date' format is very loose. There is no effort to check days in the month, months in the year etc. for example the 50/15/9999 will be accepted.

```
(birthday|birth date|birthdate)( [^ ]*){0,5}(\d\d?([-\/])\d\d?([-\/])\d{2,4})|(\d\d?([-\/])\d\d?([-\/])\d{2,4})( [^ ]*){0,5}(birthday|birth date|birthdate)
```